# Как конвертировать строку в масив node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть строка:

```
str = "[0,1,2,3]"
```

Мне нужно конвертировать её в масив arr.

Я пробовал `arr = JSON.parse(str)`, но тогда arr будет равна undefined

Comment: Можно сплитом..

Comment: `const arr = "[0,1,2,3]".replace(/(\[|\])/g, '').split(",");`

Comment: массив в строке можно записывать только в таком виде? либо вы можете поменять его(вид)?

Comment: в вашем способе arr не будет равна undefined. Проверьте еще раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let str = "[0,1,2,3]";

let arr = JSON.parse(str);

arr.forEach(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: @Zlatex приведите пример, когда `undefined`